# FME DateFormatter is not correctly setting white spaces to null and DateTimeConverter doesn't offert this option

Tags: postgresql, fme-form, date

Using FME(R) 2023.1.1.1 (20231011 - Build 23636 - WIN64) at the time of writing, I'd like to format a date field from an Excel spreadsheet into an ISO date which should then be written to a PostgreSQL (13) database (as a PG `date` field).

To this end, the workspace I'm using has an old `DateFormatter` transformer.
It is as follow:

[image]

And it used to help me a lot in this task because there are some few comments (strings) in that date column in the Excel data set. Upon those comments, some cells are simple having one or more white space characters. I need to set those dates which are not recognized as a valid dates by FME, to `null` prior to the writing in the PostgreSQL database.

Happily, the `DateFormatter` offers the option to set invalid date attributes to either `null` (which is what I need) or to keep the original value:

[image]

At this stage, the first trouble I face is that white space characters are actually NOT set to `null` but kept "as is", and FME reports that those features as successfully written to the database, without any kind of errors or warnings, but they are actually NOT inserted and this a major flaws.

When searching to debug this issue, I noticed that the `DateFormatter` has been kind of deprecated because each time I want to add such transformer in the workspace, it defaults to a [`DateTimeConvert`](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME-Form-Documentation/FME-Transformers/Transformers/datetimeconverter.htm) instead (also, there is not recent documentation on the former transformer).

In this new, `DateTimeConvert`, there is no such "replace by null" (or keep the original value) in case the date is not a valid date format:

[image]

##### So my question is:

How could I set those wrong date values to `null` programmatically?
For now, I'm having an `AttributeManager` on the rejected port where I manually set all the date fields to null, but it's not user friendly and also error-prone as there are many other date fields.

Comment: I think you need the NullAttributeMapper transformer upstream of your date formatter in your workspace https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME-Form-Documentation/FME-Transformers/Transformers/nullattributemapper.htm

Comment: I am not going to down vote because I haven't been around in this forum long enough to know the edge cases of what is considered applicable/appropriate, but this strikes me as a non-geospatial question.  Sure, a lot of people do geospatial work with FME, but does that make FME geospatial software?  Is there no other forum suited for FME non-spatial questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give you the long story, all invalid dates/datetimes used to be set to null in the output, but that wasn't a great idea because you could never tell what the original value had been. Hence, we no longer do that.

The option to replace with null obviously wasn't included on the new transformer. I suspect the reason is similar. The output from the Rejected port is now the preferred method of dealing with that data.

So, what you are doing with the AttributeManger is probably the intended solution. But I can think of a few other options that might be preferable for you.

- As Mapperz noted, you could use a NullAttributeMapper transformer to automatically map items to null. But I can see that would be hard to handle in cases where the date is just incorrectly formatted (eg 30-Fecember-2023)
- Use an AttributeValidator transformer to check whether each attribute is a valid date (or datetime - the two are different) before the DateTimeConverter, and deal with failures accordingly.
- Use an AttributeManager before the DateTimeConverter to check for valid dates and set them to null if not. You would do that using a Conditional Value, like so:

[image]

I think the last two of those work fairly well because you don't have to worry about "many other date fields". You can include all fields, whether they are good or bad. Just process any attribute that is also selected in the DateTimeConverter.

Comment: Oh, I also filed requests to update the documentation to say what happens when one value fails out of multiple selections, and to create a list of log messages when there are multiple failures (like the AttributeValidator would do). I think we could do better.

Comment: Good Answer and follow up on documentation. I have again learnt some more insight on FME.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround can you install a FME 2022 version, take a datetimeconverter from 2022 and bring it to your 2023 version(do not update it).
It should convert correct datetime and make incorrect as null.
Incorrect will still flow through rejected, but with null.
Not sure how the spaces will be handled but I suspect it will also be null.

Comment: As written in the question, white spaces are actually not set to NULL; they stay as they are: white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

[image: WorkbenchCanvas]

Above is my setup. I create 3 attributes :

1. "mydate" is a string
2. "mydate2" is the current time
3. "mydate3" are some spaces

DateTimeConverter is version 5.0 (so the one from FME 2023) and  DateTimeConverter_2 is version 4.0 (so the one from FME 2022 and not upgraded)

This is the outcome from
DateTimeConverter (version 5.0): [image: DateTimeConverter outcome 5.0]

This is the outcome from DateTimeConverter (version 4.0): [image: DateTimeConverter outcome 4.0]

So spaces are converted to null with the older version

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).